# How to sort files ascending from the name and extension en python?

Tags: python-3.x, string, sorting, lambda, substring

Could you help me to solve this problem, please?
How could I to sort this `.tif` files ascending, in python?

```
data = ['prec0000.491.tif',
 'prec0000.1.tif',
 'prec0000.750.tif',
 'prec0000.4.tif',
 'prec0000.0570.tif',
 'prec0000.0459.tif',
 'prec0000.313.tif',
 'prec0000.118.tif',
 'prec0000.0295.tif',
 'prec0000.492.tif',
 'prec0000.0752.tif',
 'prec0000.0171.tif',
 'prec0000.437.tif',
 'prec0000.2.tif']
```

I would like to sort these files ascending. For example: `['prec0000.1.tif', 'prec0000.2.tif',..., 'prec0000.0752.tif']`

I appreciate your help so much!
Thanks!

I have tried by means of this code:

```
data = sorted(data, key=lambda x: str(os.path.splitext(x)))
```

and my output is:

```
['prec0000.0171.tif',
 'prec0000.0295.tif',
 'prec0000.0459.tif',
 'prec0000.0570.tif',
 'prec0000.0752.tif',
 'prec0000.1.tif',
 'prec0000.118.tif',
 'prec0000.2.tif',
 'prec0000.313.tif',
 'prec0000.4.tif',
 'prec0000.437.tif',
 'prec0000.491.tif',
 'prec0000.492.tif',
 'prec0000.750.tif']
```